# How to actually register Signalr's IConnectionManager to Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, autofac

How to actually register IConnectionManager with *some* DependencyInjection implementation? (Unfortunely it is not Core)

I tried Autofac and some "manual" way to achieve it, but none of them works for me

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterType<IConnectionManager>().InstancePerRequest();
    IContainer container = builder.Build();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

    app.MapSignalR();
}
```

> There is no parameterless constructor defined for this object.

How can I then obtain SignalR's `IConnectionManager` in my controller?

```
private readonly IHubContext _hubContext;

public HomeController(IConnectionManager hubManager)
{
    _hubContext = hubManager.GetHubContext<TestHub>();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not to inject `IConnectionManager` to your controller. You can get `IConnectionManager` from `GlobalHost`

[GlobalHost.ConnectionManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/jj908505(v%3Dvs.118)):

> Gets the default IConnectionManager.

---

Try below solution,

```
public HomeController
{
    private static IHubContext HubContext { get; set; }; 

    //Use static constructor, as getting hub context is an expensive operation
    public static HomeController()
    {
       HubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TestHub>();
    }

   ...
}
```

**Note:** As getting default `IConnectionManger` is an expensive task, use `static` property and `static` constructor to execute only once in your application.